# ". Redirecting to" express

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express, node-modules

Salutations,
I'm currently having a hard time finding why `res.redirect('/index')` render :

```html
<p>OK. Redirecting to <a href="/index">/</a></p>
```

Instead of a direct redirection on the page.

I looked up in the file ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (ctrl + F ". Redirecting to") and found the line where it created this HTML code but I failed to understand why it is printed instead of the redirection I'm waiting for. 
Nothing about that is written in the doc on [this page](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

How do I get a normal redirection?

The base come from [eSpress-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-espress)

Comment: I don't have this issue, and I use express and the redirect function

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole relevant code snippet

Comment: Its a huge app setup, so i think there is some bad config somewere. here is the [github](https://github.com/ZaccariaWilson/Sweet-Gods-creatures)

but i think a simple npm install express  and a better look than me at the file response.js can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't render that content *instead of* redirecting, it renders that content *in addition to* redirecting.

[Here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/76eaa326ee8c4dda05568c6452286a16adb84c0b/lib/response.js#L873-L874) Express sets the appropriate `Location` header and then [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/76eaa326ee8c4dda05568c6452286a16adb84c0b/lib/response.js#L893) it sets the (default) 302 HTTP status code.

Comment: It render a page with a link that i can clic (same url), then once i clic the url change and render index. But how to disable this behaviour ? Its for a login post request.

edit: i got it ! it because im using redirect(200, 'index') instead of  redirect(302, 'index'). thank you

Answer (score 4):

for anyone down the road.

if you have a status code in your `res.redirect(202, '/to');` remove it.

this worked for me. should look like this.
`res.redirect('/to')`